# dc.js barchart valueAccessor displays object object

Tags: dc.js

I was using a dc.js rowChart to display Index averages calculated in custom reduceAdd/reduceRemove functions and it all works fine. Now, I want to change the rowChart to a barChart, and for some reason, the valueAccessor returns [object object] when hovering over the bars (representing the Index column) in the chart, instead of showing the average value. If I print out the avg value in the console though, it is defined correctly.

My csv file is structured like this:

```
Index,Model,Year,Season
Heat,Model1,1974,0
Heat,Model1,1974,1
Heat,Model1,1974,2
Heat,Model2,1974,3
Heat,Model2,1994,0
Heat,Model2,1994,1
Heat,Model2,1994,2
Heat,Model2,1994,3
Rain,Model1,1974,0
Rain,Model1,1974,1
Rain,Model1,1974,2
Rain,Model2,1974,3
Rain,Model2,1994,0
Rain,Model2,1994,1
Rain,Model2,1994,2
Rain,Model2,1994,3
```

These are the versions of the libraries:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/1.7.0/dc.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgithub.com/NickQiZhu/dc.js/master/web/js/crossfilter.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://tvinci.github.io/webs/css/dc.css"/>
```

Here is the barChart and the filter definitions:

```
indexChart = dc.barChart("#chart-index");
var indexDimension = filter.dimension(function(d) { return d.Index; });
var indexGroup = indexDimension.group();
var avgIndexGroup = indexDimension.group().reduce(reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInitial);

function reduceAdd(p, v) {
  ++p.count;
  p.total += v.value;
  p.average = p.total / p.count
  return p;
}

function reduceRemove(p, v) {
  --p.count;
  p.total -= v.value;
  p.average = p.total / p.count
  return p;
}

function reduceInitial() {
  return {count: 0, total: 0, average: 0};
}
```

And finally, the chart parameters:

```
indexChart
.width(300).height(200)
.margins({ top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 10 })    
.dimension(indexDimension)    
.group(avgIndexGroup)
.valueAccessor(function(p) { 
    //console.log("p.value.average: ", p.value.average) //displays the avg fine
    return p.value.average; 
})    
.elasticY(true)
.gap(0)
.x(d3.scale.ordinal())
.xUnits(dc.units.ordinal); // Tell dc.js that we're using an ordinal x-axis;

indexChart.yAxis().ticks(4);
```

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I presume the chart is rendering okay, so the `valueAccessor` is probably fine. I couldn't find any significant difference in the way `.title()` is computed in row charts and bar charts, but that is what you probably have to override.

Comment: I noticed that the barChart works fine without the `valueAccessor`, that is, if I filter by `indexGroup = indexDimension.group()` instead of the avg. So could there be something wrong with using `valueAccessor` with ordinal data?

Comment: Ok I can make the hover display the correct value with .title(): `.title(function(d){ return d.data.value.average; })`, but there are no numbers on the x-axis. Is it because the output of `valueAccessor` is `[object object]`?

Comment: You mean with your `valueAccessor` or without?

Comment: Ah, the y-axis values are there! I just had to translate the left margin a little more. So now everything works if I explicitly use `.title()` for the hover label and translate sufficiently. Thanks @Gordon!

Comment: You might want to change http://cdnjs.buttflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/1.7.0/dc.js to http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/1.7.0/dc.js to save yourself a redirect.

Comment: Someone edited our wiki with that stupid cloudbutt extension, so we had the wrong url for about a year. Correcting above..